# Instagram graph api working on xampp or local server but not working in live server

Tags: php, instagram-graph-api

I use Instagram API to fetch data in PHP. Everything is working fine on my local machine. I even changing my server IP but still getting the same error.Later, I checked on server console and found that it's returning 500 error on post request.  its not request limit i know for sure that.
What could be possibly wrong. ? test link :
https://www.instagram.com/p/B_qQ8RvlbwH/?__a=1

curl https://www.instagram.com/zitate.flx/?__a=1   -->works perfectly on local server but not on live server

Answer (score 0):

the main problem is with Instagram it doesn't allow requests from unknown servers if it's not a local server so to fix it you have to attach headers in the command and cookies to fix this problem eg.

```
<?PHP
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.instagram.com/p/CKeWluoJLzq/?__a=1',
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'Cookie: YOUR_COOKIE_VALUE,
'User-Agent: Instagram 9.5.2 (iPhone7,2; iPhone OS 9_3_3; en_US; en-US; 
scale=2.00; 750x1334) AppleWebKit/420+'
 ),
 ));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```